# Data tables not showing entries with special characters

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, datatables

I've just been testing data tables out and have it populated with data from my database.

Some of my entries are games with Special characters such as "Pokémon"

For example in this image:

[image]

The 2 empty entries should be :

Pokémon Version Argent: SoulSilver and Pokémon Perle

Any ideas what i can do so it shows all entries?

Comment: Please show your code. This could help us finding the error.

Comment: Its the data tables Example code. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: I don't think anyone will look for the "example code" arround the web, to find a sulution for you :-) I guess it's just encoding problem. Make sure your page is UTF-8 and your js is loaded as UTF-8. First thing I would try is to analyze headers and server response (for datables data) in the browser devtools.

Comment: I can't really put the whole of data tables script up here? Thanks ill check out what you suggested.